# How to correctly do transaction with multiple context and multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6

I have two databases and two datacontexts (I am using code first approach). So code:

```
using (var tr1 = internalDb.Database.BeginTransaction())
using (var tr2 = externalDb.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        //Some changes to internalDb (inserted)
        //Some changes to externalDb (update, deleting some values)

        internalDb.SaveChanges();
        externalDb.SaveChanges();
        tr1.Commit();
        tr2.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        tr1.Rollback();
        tr2.Rollback();
        _log.Error(exc);
    }
```

Everything worked fine, but one time I get incident: somewhere in the middle of process, I had very short (5 sec) network down event. After rollback, data deleted from externalDb, tr2 was corrupted - was lost small chunk of data (I don't know: maybe 128 letters, maybe a little more).

So I wonder: how can it be??? Entity framework transaction != SQL transaction? Or maybe I'm doing transactions incorrect way?

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I'm doing transactions incorrect way?

You need distributed transactions. Microsoft has [MSDTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator). Once configured properly it can be automatically used in .NET using [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Using scope As New TransactionScope()
{
    try
    {
        //Some changes to internalDb (inserted)
        //Some changes to externalDb (update, deleting some values)

        internalDb.SaveChanges();
        externalDb.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        _log.Error(exc);
    }
scope.Complete()
}
```